# libspotify API: sp_album_year doesn't always return the release year

Tags: spotify

If I search with "tag:new", spotify returns a list of new albums but some of the albums doesn't show the release year. But if I search these albums with album names, the release year does exist. Both of these search use same APIs internally (use **sp_search_create** to start search and use **sp_album_year** to get the year in search_complete callback) , why the result is different?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Album years don't exist until you do an `sp_album_browse()` on the albums. I guess one of these searches is triggering an album browse internally.

Comment: Some of the albums do show the release year but some don't when I search new albums with "tag:new". That's one search. search complete means album is loaded. Are you saying album year doesn't exit even if album is loaded?

Comment: Quite a lot of albums have no release year associated with them.

Comment: The albums that don't have release year returned by searching "tag:new" can get the release year by searching their album names. That means the release year does exit.

Comment: I think you may have misread my answer. Also, `search_complete` does *not* mean albums are loaded, although some *may* be at that point. The only reliable way to ensure you have all data for an album is to do an album browse.

Comment: The API document says when search_complete callback is called, **sp_album_is_loaded** returns non-zero for the objects contained in the search result. Anyway, I'll do the album browse as you suggested. Thanks.